# Analog mux with active low enable.I/P and O/P state when enable is High

Tags: digital-logic, analog, logic-gates, multiplexer, analog-switch

I am using this mux ([74LV4051D,118](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LV4051.pdf))from Nxperia for one of my applications.The functional table is given below.

When the Enable is High S0, S1, S2 are don't care, and the switch is off.

May I know when Enable is high,can I assume both I/P (S0-S2) and O/P(Z) are at high impedance state.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *May I know when Enable is high, can I assume both I/P (S0-S2) and
> O/P(Z) are at high impedance state.*

Focus on the last line of the table in your question: -

[image]

A switch being off will mean high impedance. Inputs S0 to S2 will remain high impedance (because they are inputs) irrespective of the state of the enable input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't understand exactly what's the behavior of an analog switch (aka CMOS transmission gate) is. And this analog mux/demux conceptually is just 8 analog switch which have one terminal in common. The added complexity just comes from the selection/decode logic.

The high impedance state of a 3-state gate means the output is completely disconnected from the internal circuitry.

However, in this case, when the mux/demux is enabled, the selected "input" Y is electrically connected to the "output" Z.

I used quotes because what is input and what is output in an analog switch is arbitrary. In reality the selected terminal Y is connected to Z almost like a wire connected the two terminals.

Therefore there is no "high impedance state" as you would have in a 3-state output because Y is connected to Z and for the circuit to do anything sensible either Y or Z (or BOTH) must be connected to something.

IF your question is "once the chip is enabled, are Y and Z connected to something else internally", the answer is *no*.

You can understand the switch operation by looking at the internal
schematic (emphasis mine):

[image]

The connection between (any) Y and Z is done with a paralleled PMOS/NMOS pair (in yellow) and when the switch is enabled the current path is that in red.

Once both the PMOS and the NMOS are switched off, Y and Z are more or less insulated from the internal circuitry of the chip.

Comment: Thank you. My question is when the enable is high(This chip has an active-low enable), Y and Z will be in open circuit condition or not.

Comment: @HARITO I think I already answered indirectly. But yes, the last row of the table you posted give you the answer: every switch is open. There is no internal connection to anything (in a first approximation).

Comment: OP seems to understand perfectly well *exactly what's the behavior of an analog switch (aka CMOS transmission gate) is*. When disabled, the outputs will go high impedance and that's what they're questioning. There is a high-impedance pin state, it's shown in the truth table. Besides that, a very confusing answer to try and make sense of, downvoted I'm afraid.

Comment: @TonyM You are entitled to you opinions, ofc, but "very confusing" is quite a lot. I concede it was not spot-on, since I was mislead by the fact the OP posted the table where the answer was in its last line (as pointed out by Andy Aka's answer).  *OP seems to understand **perfectly well** exactly what's the behavior of an analog switch (aka CMOS transmission gate) is*. Sorry, no. If they did, they wouldn't have posted a table with the answer in plain view and asked for confirmation. The *question* is confusing. ...

Comment: @TonyM ... When I realized the OP problem was "I'm not sure if the CMOS switch acts as a true switch" I added the explanation with the figure of the internal circuitry. What's confusing in that?